# Trying to make wpbot which adds data to googlesheets. Used google-spreadsheet npm package

Tags: node.js, node-modules, google-sheets-api

\node_modules\google-spreadsheet\lib\GoogleSpreadsheetWor
const rows = await this.addRows([rowValues], options);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addRows')
at new Promise ()
at addRow (node:internal/util:350:12)
at accessSpreadsheet (C:\Users\user\Desktop\wpbott\index1.js:36:36)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

```
const addDataToSheet = async (sheetId, data) => {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
    async function accessSpreadsheet() {
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        client_email: creds.client_email,
        private_key: creds.private_key,
        });
    await doc.loadInfo(); 
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
    console.log(doc.title); 
    console.log(sheet.title);
    console.log(sheet.rowCount);
    const rowValues = Object.values(data);
    const addRow = promisify(sheet.addRow)
    await promisify(sheet.addRow)(rowValues);
    }
accessSpreadsheet();
};
```

```js
await addDataToSheet('1mbvrmGbwZBlPYaYSf-Ftoeoz9Jirhmeg1HmLre_KlQ4',{
      Name: userData[from].Name,
      Age: userData[from].Age,
      Gender: userData[from].Gender
    });
```

I'm sending data like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to set header row.

```
await sheet.setHeaderRow(["name", "age", "gender"])
await sheet.addRows([data]);
```

above await promisify.
So,

```
const addDataToSheet = async (sheetId, data) => {
  console.log(data)
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: creds.client_email,
    private_key: creds.private_key,
  });
  await doc.loadInfo(); 
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
  await sheet.setHeaderRow(["name", "age", "gender"])
  await sheet.addRows([data]);
};
```